# Considerations for connecting 5 pin wire cables and interfaces to USB?

Tags: usb

I found a module breakout board that has a generic looking 5 pin USB internal motherboard looking plug. The module comes with a 5 pin connector which is in the second picture below.

My ultimate goal is to connect to my computer's usb port. Is there an easy way to solder on a usb? I am confused as the interface looks NOTHING like a usb port. Can someone give me some advice on how to connect this? thanks!

[image]

[image]

Comment: That looks like a FFC "flat flexible connector" - do you have a datasheet for the module?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not exactly clear, what you are saying. What I got is:
 1. you have a USB device, that provides only wire leads
 2. you want to connect to external USB port of the computer

You can cut an existing USB cable and solder or wrap wires together. Normally there would be some sort of filtering on any USB peripheral, so I guess you can try without anything fancier than that. Typical USB color coding you can see [here](https://turbofuture.com/computers/Color-Coded-Wire-inside-the-USB)